# After upgrading to fedora 27 can execute binary file

Tags: linux, fedora

So this is a specific binary file. I had both in my laptop and my desktop a software called IVMs-4200 from hikvision I dont think they support anymore this software for linux, since I can find it on their website.  Well the thing is that I had fedora 23 and 22 and the software worked fine, i formatted both machines and installed fedora 27. I kept both home files from the previous installation so I just had the software untouched in my home folder.  And I can no longer execute the binary file
I get this

```
$ ./iVMS-4200 
bash: ./iVMS-4200: No such file or directory
```

but the file is there, if I click on it nothing happens

```
$ ls
ChannelPicture  ClientRestore.xml  iVMS-4200  Linux  log  Log  maintain  NetSys.db  PlugIns  translations
```

with sh I get this

```
$ sh ./iVMS-4200 
./iVMS-4200: ./iVMS-4200: cannot execute binary file
```

I wish I could get a longer explanation if a library is missing but I get only this.

I dont know why it tells me that there is  no such file or directory

```
$ /home/jdc/Programas/Camaras/iVMS-4200 
bash: /home/jdc/Programas/Camaras/iVMS-4200: No such file or directory
```

It has execution permits

```
$ ls -al
total 11300
drwxrwxr-x. 10 jdc jdc     4096 Jun 30  2016 .
drwxr-xr-x.  9 jdc jdc     4096 Feb 15 00:12 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  4 jdc jdc     4096 Jul 27  2015 ChannelPicture
-rw-rw-r--.  1 jdc jdc      219 Sep 21  2015 ClientRestore.xml
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 jdc jdc 11438896 Aug 28  2013 iVMS-4200
drwxrwxr-x.  6 jdc jdc     4096 Jul 27  2015 Linux
drwxrw-r--.  3 jdc jdc     4096 Jul 27  2015 log
drwxrw-r--.  2 jdc jdc     4096 Jul 27  2015 Log
drwxrwxr-x.  3 jdc jdc     4096 Jun 30  2016 maintain
-rw-r--r--.  1 jdc jdc    83968 Jun 30  2016 NetSys.db
drwxrwxr-x.  3 jdc jdc     4096 Jul 27  2015 PlugIns
drwxrwxr-x.  6 jdc jdc     4096 Jun 28  2013 .svn
drwxrwxr-x.  3 jdc jdc     4096 Aug 28  2013 translations
```

Running the command `file`

```
$ file iVMS-4200 
iVMS-4200: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1478ff289251b33cdc12e229efd816d50add28a9, not stripped
```

Comment: You can run `ldd filename` to see what might be missing.

Comment: besides `ldd`, please run `file iVMS-4200`

Comment: Hi, I used ld because ldd wasnt working for this file I just needed to install a bunch of .i686 libraries, from mesa to libstdc

Comment: You are trying to run a 32-bit binary in a 64 bit system.

Comment: (TBH, I forgot I can now close `linux` questions single-handedly. Have to be more careful)

Comment: I found the exactly binary of the OP at http://itunedvr.ru/_ftp/HIKVISION/iVMS4200-Linux.tar.gz